# Want to embed talking flash character

Tags: flash, shockwave

I have a flash video file with this sample code

```
<object id="objvideo" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
 data="http://www.ausfis.com/images/Intro/ausfis_intro_230309.swf"
 width="336" height="288">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.ausfis.com/images/Intro/ausfis_intro_230309.swf"/>
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
<param name="menu" value="false"/>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.ausfis.com/images/Intro/ausfis_intro_230309.swf" width="555" height="412" wmode="transparent" menu="false">
</object>
```

I want it to appear on my homepage once for every user.

How to do it?

I want to do something like what this website has;

http://www.ausfis.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with css , like:

```
<style>
    object,embed{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;             // Your X coordinate here
        top: 0;               // Your Y coordinate here  
    }
</style>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/AKC7Y/